# Javascript : Call array with function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I get a little confuse about assigment from my lecturer, he ask me to call array using function :

```
a[0]["Company_name"] = "Microsoft";
a[0]["employee_total"] = 20;
```

use function :

```
function find_employeeTotal(a, Company_name){
}
```

Output :

```
Mirosoft
20
```

Please help me , Thank you

Comment: You don't have to *call* the Array, you have to provide the Array and the Company Name to your function, then search the Array for the Company Name and return the total number of employees. What have you tried so far?

Comment: "To call" means to write the variable name. For example to show it as alert dialog, have `alert(a[0]["Company_name"]);` and see what happens. It's really too trivial to fit here in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Presumably before that there was `var a = []; a[0] = {};` or `var a = [{}];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a[0]["Company_name"] = "Microsoft";
a[0]["employee_total"] = 20;
a[1]["Company_name"] = "Apple";
a[1]["employee_total"] = 10;
Company_name = "Microsoft";
Total_Employees = find_employeeTotal(a, Company_name);

    function find_employeeTotal(a, Company_name){
       for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i){
          if(a[i]["Company_name"] == Company_name){
             return a[i]["employee_total"];
          }
       }
       return "Company doesn't exist in array!";
    }
```

Since you have a two-dimensional array I think you want to query the first dimension to find the correct company and then the second dimension to find the total number of emplyoees. This should do it.

Let me know if I got it all wrong.